# Iterative for loop and lambda function

Tags: c++, iterator

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Point
{
    int x, y;
    Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}
};

int main()
{
    Point arr[] = {
        Point(4,2), Point(0,3), Point(1,2)
                    };

    std::sort(arr, arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(Point), [](Point a, Point b){return a.x<b.x;});

    return 0;
}
```

Now, i am supposed to write iterative for loop (built in cpp for_each loop) which prints out all of the elements of the array, where, as a iteration variable we must use auto reference.

Now, this confuses me a bit, since i know this can be done without any iteration variables or something, like this:

```
std::for_each(arr,arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(Point), [](Point a){cout<<a.x<<a.y<<std::endl;}
```

Obviously, this is not what i am asked to do, so, since i never found myself using iteration variables when dealing with for_each loop, i'd like to find out how am i supposed to do that properly, especially considering the fact that i have to use auto reference. Any help appreciated!

Comment: And [here](https://amiteshsingh.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/how-to-use-stdfor_each-on-standard-c-array/) you find an example on how to do it with a std::for_each instead of a range-for loop, if that's what you're looking for

Comment: `for_each` is not a loop, it is a function. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) has an article on the "foreach" loop construct with examples in numerous languages, including C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a solution based on `std::for_each`, you can do the following.

```
std::for_each(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr),
    [](auto& p){ cout << p.x << p.y << "\n"; });
    // ^^^^^ auto reference
```

Here, you have an `auto&` reference for the object that you intend to do something with in each iteration (in the case above, it would make sense to use `const auto&`).

This is almost identical to the range-based for loop [suggested by @cdhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57799592/9593596). The only interesting point to note here is that `std::for_each` is one of the few (the only?) exception to the rule that callables passed to STL algorithms must not have side effects. In this case, writing to the global `std::cout` object is a side effect, and `std::for_each` explicitly allows that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, where do i even use auto reference p here?

Comment: The lambda gets an `auto&` reference as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for the [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto & i : arr) {
    std::cout << i.x << ',' << i.y << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Since OP asked for auto ref, I'd suggest changing to `auto& i`

Comment: @nada Indeed, I had it that way originally but thought OP was asking for `auto` only. Missed the part about it being a reference.

Comment: @cdhowie thanks for the reply, however, i thought that i am supposed to use for_each loop in this case since it says "built-in cpp for-each loop" to be used, anyway, im kinda confused about this

Comment: @cdummie The "built-in for-each" loop _is_ the range-for loop. They are the same thing... unless your book/professor actually means `std::for_each`? But from your question it sounds like they did not mean that. An actual quote of what you're expected to do would be helpful.

Comment: @cdhowie "write iterative for loop (built in cpp for_each loop) which prints out all of the elements of the array, where, as a iteration variable we must use auto reference. " That would be the actual quote (Translated to english, though)

Comment: @cdummie Then it probably is `std::for_each` and lubgr's answer would be correct. Note that both styles (`std::for_each` and range-for) are going to generate either identical or nearly-identical machine code.

Comment: [naming]: I would rename `i` by `p` or `point`. `i` is mostly used as counter.